# Getting the rate of change of a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm fairly new to Python. 
My goal is to press a button and a counter (`counta`) goes up by 1 every time I press 'a'. 
Now I want - for example print out - how many times I've pressed the 'a' button within 10 seconds (for example).

The code is working fine like this. Now i only want to add this feature to print the chagne rate. Any ideas?

Until now my code looks like this:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Listener
import sched, time 

s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)

counta = 0
Timer = 0
On = True

def on_press(key):
  if key.char == 'a':
      #print("")
      global counta
      counta += 1
      #print("Aktuell" + str(counta))
  elif key.char == 'p':
      print(int(counta/3))
  else:
      print("wrong button")
      print("a = counta")

listener = Listener(on_press=on_press)
listener.start()
while On:
    print(int(counta//3))
    print(counta)
    time.sleep(1)

listener.join()
```

Comment: please, please, format your code. And use understandable variable names. (counta10s1 isnt really good). while On. never seen that. Reformat and make it look nice and i will help.
PS, is it working? Or getting any error? Be as clear as you can about what the problem is.

Comment: So what's the problem with your current code? What does it do? What specifically isn't working? By being more detailed about what it's donig now, we can be more detailed with help, without needing to actually give you the whole solution. It's better if we can help you to help yourself debug this :)

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you are looking for? And what do you mean by change rate?

```
from pynput.keyboard import Listener
import time


counta = 0
end = time.time() + 10


def on_press(key):
    global counta
    if key.char == 'a':
        counta += 1
    elif key.char == 'p':
        print(int(counta/3))
    else:
        print("Falsche Taste!")
        print("a = counta")


listener = Listener(on_press=on_press)
listener.start()

while True:
    if end - time.time() >= 0:
        pass
        # print(end - time.time())
    else:
        print(counta)
        counta = 0
        end = time.time() + 10

listener.join()
```